# Are they two subordinate clauses?

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clauses

Consider the following sentence I got from github tutorial.

> If you’ve made a change that you feel would benefit the community as a whole, you should definitely consider contributing back.

The part that I cannot classify their grammatical position:

> you’ve made a change that you feel would benefit the community

## My atttempt

- you have made a change
- the change that I feel
- the change that would benefit the community

It looks like there are two subordinate clauses here. It is grammatical?

## Edit

I don't 100% understand the available answer actually.

I am trying to create another sentence with the same pattern as follows.

- He discovered a small island.
- The island that we live.
- The island that is located in South-East Asia.

So combining all of them becomes

> He discovered a small island that we live (is) located in South-East Asia.

Is `(is)` probably optional?

Comment: I open for other answers that can be understood better.

Comment: You live *on* an island. He discovered a small island on which we live, which is located in South-East Asia.

Comment: Or He discovered the small island that we live on, located in South-East Asia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *If you’ve* [*made a change* [*that you feel* [*would* [*benefit the community*
>   …]]]]

I’ve bracketed the subordinate clauses. There are four in all.

The *understood* subject of "made" is "you", and of "would" and "benefit" is "a change".

Comment: Is it possible to change the order of `you feel` and `would benefit...`. Something like
`you’ve made a change that would benefit the community you feel`?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer No, it would be awkward.

Comment: "He discovered the small island in SE Asia that we live on"

Comment: But it becomes unclear because ones can also interpret "we live on another island in SE Asia in which the island he discovered lies".

Comment: That's not true. It entails that "He discovered a small island"; "We live on that island"; "The island is in Asia".

Comment: In my understanding a subordinate clause begins with one word of where, whose, who, that, which, whom. But some  subordinate clauses you mentioned don't explicitly have such a word. It is confusing.

Comment: You're thinking of relative clauses. Non-finite clauses don't have those words. There are three non-finite clauses in the sentence you cited.